# Oracle Discoverer like app native for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, reporting

Can someone point me at some web based apps that work like Oracle Discoverer but native for SQL Server.  We already the SQL connector running to actually use disco, but was wondering what other options there were.  Not really interested in setting up connections inside of excel.

thanks.

--update 3/15/12

[Oracle Discoverer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/discoverer/overview/index.html) is a set of BI tools that enable web based access to your data.  I'm looking specifically for the ad hoc data manipulation it does, as well as the admin tool set that exposes data, defines relationships, manaages data access, and defines calculated data items.

Comment: Can you describe what Oracle Discoverer does?  You'll probably get more answers that way.

Comment: @mrdenny - same sort of thing as Report Builder

Comment: updated my description.  I'm not as familiar with Report Builder, but it can do canned report delivery.  I'm more interested in the ad hoc query and admin tools.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005+ comes with an ad-hoc reporting tool called [Report Builder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/ff657833), which does much the same sort of thing as Discoverer.  This will probably get you what you need.

SQL Server It also comes with a reporting tool called Reporting Services (SSRS), a SQL based tool that does the same sort of thing as Crystal Reports or Oracle Reports.  SSRS will consume a variety of data sources, including Oracle.  One key point to note about SSRS is that you can use it as a medium for publishing reports built with Report Builder.

Comment: Thanks - took a quick look at Report Builder, but didn't think it had what I was looking for, but I'll dive in again.  I'll clarify my original post, but I'm most interested in ad hoc reporting (vs canned published reports), and the administrative tools that disco has to expose data to certain sets of users.

Comment: If you want data security, you might want to look into using SSAS cubes.  Take a look at dimension security.

Comment: Report models do the same thing as Discoverer End-user layers.  If you want to partition data access to different groups with Report Builder you would need to set up multiple report models and grant the permissions on the individual report models.